# JavaScript/NodeJS Callback within a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, user-management

I'm using the 'user-management' package in Node, and I have a callback within a callback, within a callback.   But the final result doesn't return.  This is my main NodeJS module:

```
 playerManagement.login(data.username, data.pw, function (result) {

      console.log(result) <-- statement never reached

      if (result == "fail") {
        socket.emit('client', { type: 'login', result : 'fail'});
      } else {
        connections[playerindex++] = {'username' : username, 'sockid' : socket.id, 'token' : result };
        socket.emit('client', { type: 'login', result : 'success', username : username });
        console.log(connections);
      }

  });
```

Then I have an external module with the function:

```
playerModule.prototype.login = function(username, password) {

var o = this;

o.user.load(function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        o.user.authenticateUser(username, password, function(err, result) {

            if (!result.userExists) {
              console.log('Invalid username');
              return "fail";
            } else if (!result.passwordsMatch) {
              console.log('Invalid password');
              return "fail";
            } else {
              console.log('User token is: ' + result.token); <--- this is reached.
              return result.token;
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log('error logging in');
        return "fail";
    }
});
```

So I'm guessing I need to return the value to the "load" function callback, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You should use promises.

Comment: If you want to accept a callback, you need to actually have a callback parameter, and call it.

Comment: Because your `login` function definition doesn't have callback as an argument,

Comment: You can't return an async result.  Your function returns long before the async result is obtained.  Instead, you must use promises or callbacks to communicate back the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Change the definition of `login` with the following.

```
playerModule.prototype.login = function(username, password, callback)  {

  var o = this;

  o.user.load(function (err) {
  if (!err) {
    o.user.authenticateUser(username, password, function(err, result) {

        if (!result.userExists) {
          console.log('Invalid username');
          return callback("fail");
        } else if (!result.passwordsMatch) {
          console.log('Invalid password');
          return callback("fail");
        } else {
          console.log('User token is: ' + result.token); <--- this is reached.
          return callback(result.token);
        }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('error logging in');
    return callback("fail");
  }
});
```